# How to Make Devise Controllers Code DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I had to overide Devise controllers code, Controllers namely Registrations and Sessions controllers.
I did this successfully. Now both of these controllers share a set of common code. So my question is where to write these code.

How can i make it Dry, i think there should be a Parent controller for these Devise controllers. In case please help me to achieve that..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use controller concerns http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: Thanks @mdemolin. let me check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to put common code into a seperate file which you place into the 'concerns' folder.

Something like that:

```
module CommonDeviseCode
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  your common code here
```

After that you can include this file in both controllers.

Comment: argh, duplicate answer: mdemolin just did it in a comment.

Comment: Ok let me try that @klausinho :). Thanks.